# python string parse with @ and space

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse all the usernames when a user write an `@` expression in a string.

Example:

```
I want to tell @susan and @rick that I love you all.
```

I want to get `['susan', 'rick']` from the string, how to write the parse expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not very hard to write an expression for this.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'@(\S+)', ' I want to tell @susan and @rick that I love you all')
['susan', 'rick']
```

Or use `\w` which matches any word character.

```
>>> re.findall(r'@(\w+)', ' I want to tell @susan and @rick that I love you all')
['susan', 'rick']
```

Comment: Keep on spoonfeeding :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "I want to tell @susan and @rick that I love you all."
>>> m = re.findall(r'@[a-z]+', s)
>>> m
['@susan', '@rick']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

# input string
myStr = "tell @susan and @rick that"

# match
names = re.findall(r"@(\w+)", myStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers using regexes work well too. For variety, here is a list comp.

```
>>> s = 'I want to tell @susan and @rick that I love you all.'    
>>> [i.strip('@') for i in s.split() if '@' in i]
['susan', 'rick']
```

Comment: Eh, good luck explaining that code to your boss. This seems to always generate a garbage string too, which is the section before the first `@`.